# Border in a UIButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I dragged A round rect button into the nib and set a background image for the button. However, the image didn't fill up the whole space, it left out a narrow border on the sides of the button. How do I get rid of this border? Thanks.

Comment: post image so i can identify the prob

Comment: In nib Change Button type Rounded Rect to custom

Comment: Used custom button instead of Round Rect button. and set it's border in code like below

[btn.layer setCornerRadius:3.0];

// btn is UIbutton object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use a custom background image for the `UIButton`, you should change the button type to `UIButtonTypeCustom` instead of `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect`.

(you can do this in the *Interface Builder* as well)

Comment: To try that, I dragged another round rect button into the nib and changed its type to 'custom' in the attributes inspector. I then set the background image for it but the borderline appeared again.

Comment: it is really strange behaviour, because when the `UIButton`'s type is `UIButtonTypeCustom` the button won't get any unique style from the system. you can set most of everything on the button freely. this would be the point of the _custom_ buttons.